# Conjecture about arcsin and $\sqrt{\quad}$

Tags: trigonometry, radicals, pi, inverse-function

Let $r(a,b)$ be a rational number depending on $a,b$ and nonnegative. For every $b$ there is an $a$ such that $r(a,b)$ is not $0$.

Let $C(a,b)$ be a squarefree positive integer depending on $b$ and different for every $b$.

Consider for positive integers $I,J$ :

$$ S_J = \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^I \arcsin\left( r(i,j) \sqrt {C(i,j)} \right) $$

Where $ r(i,j) \sqrt C(i,j) $ is always smaller than $1$.

Conjecture G

For $J>2$

$$ S_J \neq 2 \pi $$

Is this true ??

Comment: Please clarify your sums, writing them in the style of $$\sum_{i=0}^m\,,$$and state whether $I$ is finite and, if so, what lower bound it must satisfy. (It is clear that $J\geqslant3$.)

Comment: @John Bentin. Tnx ! I did it.

Comment: Why do you write $C(a,b)$ if it depends only on $b$? And do you have any reasons, however vague, for believing the conjecture true? Oh, and when you say $r(a,b)$ is a *fraction*, do you mean a *rational* number?

Comment: Yes by fraction I mean a rational number. I thought that was pretty standard , Although we can make fractions of nonintegers in principle.  I was unable to find a counterexample and the addition theorem for sine did not convince me of the existance of a counterexample.  I tend to use double index for double sums , No particular reason. @Harald Hanche-Olsen

Comment: "Fraction" meaning "rational number" is by no means standard, e.g., $\pi/3$ is a fraction.  There was a pretty lengthy discussion about this exact topic not too long ago I think.

Comment: The reason for the assumption that it is standard probably comes from the fact that we learn fractions BEFORE pi or irrationals , hence Then those are rational.